# How to read a particular partition of kafka topic using KafkaSpout

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am using Storm as the consumer to read from a Kafka topic. I am able to read the topic completely when the producer starts producing messages. However, if I try reading logs from a particular topic partition, it exits with an error.

The things which I tried are:

```
    Broker p1 = new Broker("localhost:9092");
    GlobalPartitionInformation info = new GlobalPartitionInformation() ;
    info.addPartition(0,p1) ; // 0th partition is mapped to broker p1
    StaticHosts hosts = new StaticHosts(info) ;
    SpoutConfig cfg = new SpoutConfig(hosts,topic,zkroot, spouteID) ;
    KafkaSpout spout = new KafkaSpout(cfg);
    
    //topology
     TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
     builder.setSpout(KAFKA_SPOUT_ID, kspout, numSpoutExecutors);
...

//whereNumber of workers
 int numSpoutExecutors = 1;
```

Is it possible to 'Read from a topic partition'? There is workaround to use Kafka consumer API to read from a topic partition and emit using the spout but I do not want to use it?

## EDIT 1

The error which is a runtime error which aborts following the exception

```
41226 [Thread-8-kafka-solar-spout] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:97) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:69) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:128) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:74) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:64) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:89) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.StaticCoordinator.<init>(StaticCoordinator.java:34) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:92) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3284$fn__3299.invoke(executor.clj:520) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:429) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
41228 [Thread-8-kafka-solar-spout] ERROR backtype.storm.daemon.executor -
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:97) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:69) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:128) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) ~[kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:74) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:64) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:89) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.StaticCoordinator.<init>(StaticCoordinator.java:34) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:92) ~[storm-kafka-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3284$fn__3299.invoke(executor.clj:520) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:429) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
41263 [Thread-8-kafka-solar-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/REnszs3G is the complete error which I see on execution of the Consumer which tries to read single partition of the topic.

Comment: What version of KafkaSpout are you using? The old one will not give you much control. Why do you want to read from dedicated partition?